# How can I deny from a certain IP address but still show a custom error page with Apache2?

Tags: apache-2.2, http-status-code-403, errordocument, custom-errors, 500

I have
In my web root `/home/www/` I have an `.htaccess` file to ban IP addresses:

```
order allow,deny
deny from 1.2.3.4
deny from 2.3.4.5
allow from all

ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.htm
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.htm
```

I have also tried it this way with the error statements:

```
ErrorDocument 500 /home/www/errors/500.htm
ErrorDocument 403 /home/www/errors/403.htm
```

I have created an error directory, `/home/www/errors` which contains the following files:

```
403.htm
500.htm
.htaccess
```

In the errors directory `.htaccess` I have set the rules:

```
order deny,allow
allow from all
```

If I put my IP in the root .htaccess file I can't browse the site. I get an error:

> Forbidden - You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

However if I browse to /errors/500.htm I can see that page in my browser, so I know the subdirectory `.htaccess` seems to allow those files to be loaded.

What am I doing wrong? How can I deny from a certain IP address but still show a custom error page with Apache2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would be much easier to simply redirect people coming from the blocked IPs to an error page:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} 1.2.3.4
RewriteRule .* /CustomError.html [R=403]
```